# Android: SVG image loaded erroneous

Tags: android, svg

[image]I am using `svg-android-1.1` for displaying SVG graphics. It works, but the image is rendered erroneously (I attached it). I am wondering what I am doing wrong, its actually only lines? Did I miss to set something?

Here is my code for loading the picture it:

```
ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.svgImgView);
        imgView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(),
                R.raw.stroke_test);
        Drawable drawable = svg.createPictureDrawable();
        imgView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: svgandroid has lots of missing features.  You could try my library AndroidSVG, which has fuller support for the SVG spec.

Comment: Thank you. Your library does it correctly!